# how do get correct error message using ajax json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Here i'm storing span values into a database. It's working fine. I'm now facing a problem with ajax return error message. For example in my save.php code i changed my database table name `sample` to `simple` (i don't have a `simple` database table). In the mainpage I want to get the error message like "this `simple` database table name doesn't exists". **But it always shows Data saved succesfully.**

I've searched on some other sites. Some people say I should use json to get the proper error message. But, I don't how to do that. How do I get the correct error message using json and ajax? I think this is very simple. But, I'm new to ajax.

**save.php**

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    $get = $_POST['content'];
    try
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sample (divvalue) VALUES (?)"); 
        $conn->errorInfo();
        $stmt->bindParam('1', $get, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        'Error : ' .$e->getMessage();
    }
    if($stmt)
    {
        echo 1;
    }
?>
```

**ajax.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#save").click(function (e) {   
    var span_contents = $('#ele').html();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'save.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            content: span_contents
         },
      success: function(data){
            if(data == '1')
            {
                $('#status')
                .addClass('return')
                .html('Data saved succesfully')
                .fadeIn('fast')
                .delay(3000)
                .fadeOut('slow')
            }
            else
            {
                $('#status')
                .addClass('error')
                .html('Error occured')
                .fadeIn('fast')
                .delay(3000)
                .fadeOut('slow')
            }
        }   
     }); 
   });
});
```

**mainpage.php**

```
<span id="ele" class="ele" contenteditable >element</span>
<input type="button" id="save" value="save" />
<br />
<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: @Beginner..the problem in your code is there is no error callback in your jquery ajax call..

Comment: ur javascript is done right, but PHP is not. You need to echo on error too.

Comment: check var_dump($stmt), if it is true even with the invalid table name., then move the success "echo" inside the "if". So you will get proper error prompt.

Answer (score 2):

In your code i think every time it returns one. In your `catch` block you need to return another value like 0.

```
try
{
    if($stmt){
        echo "1";
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Error : ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

Also you can add an error handler in ajax function like ,

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(data){
        if(data == '1')
        {
            $('#status')
            .addClass('return')
            .html('Data saved succesfully')
            .fadeIn('fast')
            .delay(3000)
            .fadeOut('slow')
        }
        else
        {
            $('#status')
            .addClass('error')
            .html('Error occured')
            .fadeIn('fast')
            .delay(3000)
            .fadeOut('slow')
        }
    },
    //another handlers and properties
    error:function(error){
        $('#status')
        .addClass('error')
        .html('Error occured')
        .fadeIn('fast')
        .delay(3000)
        .fadeOut('slow')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows using `json` data

**PHP :**

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    $get = $_POST['content'];
    try
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sample (divvalue) VALUES (?)"); 
        $conn->errorInfo();
        $stmt->bindParam('1', $get, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt)
        {
            echo '{"status":1}';
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo '{"status":0,"Error" : "' .$e->getMessage().'"}';
    }

?>
```

**JQUERY :**

```
success: function(data){          
     $('#status')
        .addClass('return')
        .html(data.status?'Data saved succesfully':'Error'+data.Error)
        .fadeIn('fast')
        .delay(3000)
        .fadeOut('slow')          
},
dataType:'json'
```

Comment: data.status=="something" since if data.status contains for example a blank, that will be truthy too

Comment: @mplungjan : yes I know. But it looks more simple

Answer (score 1):

Please update your code. It was ur PHP, which needs to echo on error too.

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    $get = $_POST['content'];
    try
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sample (divvalue) VALUES (?)"); 
        $conn->errorInfo();
        $stmt->bindParam('1', $get, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo 'Error : ' .$e->getMessage();
    }
    if($stmt)
    {
        echo 1;
    }
?>
```

And in your JavaScript too.

```
$(function() {
  $("#save").click(function (e) {   
    var span_contents = $('#ele').html();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'save.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            content: span_contents
         },
      error: function(data){//callback option is invoked, if the request fails.
            $('#status')
                .addClass('error')
                .html('Error occured')
                .fadeIn('fast')
                .delay(3000)
                .fadeOut('slow');
      },
      success: function(data){//callback option is invoked, if the request succeeds. 
            $('#status')
                .addClass('return')
                .html('Data saved succesfully')
                .fadeIn('fast')
                .delay(3000)
                .fadeOut('slow');
        }
     }); 
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
if($stmt)
{
    echo 1;
}
```

Always evalute to true, try (for test) to do echo "2" without modify anything else. 
Try also adding an echo in the catch block.
Also you can check with the devTools in the network tab what does the response return.

Answer (score 0):

**Please use the following syntax for your ajax call:**

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'save.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            content: span_contents
         },
      success: function(data){
            if(data == '1')
            {
                $('#status')
                .addClass('return')
                .html('Data saved succesfully')
                .fadeIn('fast')
                .delay(3000)
                .fadeOut('slow')
            },
     error: function(data){
            alert('Your error message here');
        }

       });
```

When ever you get an error, the error callback of the jquery ajax call will be fired

Answer (score 0):

A Good standard way is to use JSON as below

```
catch
{
 echo {"status":"failure","message":"The Error message goes here"};
}
if($stmt)
{
 echo {"status":"success","message":"Data saved successfully"};
}
```

and in your ajax success function check like this

```
  dataType:'json',
 success: function(data){
            if(data.status == 'success')
            {
                // do the required
            }
           else{
                // do the required
           }
  }
```

You can add more variables as required like status and message in the return string